# Fluoroquinolone mitochondrial and genomic DNA adduct

Tags: genetics, microbiology, reproduction, cancer

What could be possible consequences of covalent bond mitochondrial and genomic DNA adduct by Fluoroquinolones, our study was done by Fluoroquinolone Toxicity Study NFP. All 50+ participates who took Ciprofloxacin and Levofloxacin were positive. In vitro study showed DNA adduct after 3.61 min. We are FQAD victims not scientists. We would like to know what may be consequences of DNA adduct.

Comment: As a new user you are welcome to SE Biology, however you should be aware that there are a couple problems with your question that might have been avoided if you had taken the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help on answering questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The first is to express yourself clearly — 'mt' and 'n' should be written in full in the title for clarity and to help indexing. The second is that questions here should be self-contained. Nobody should have to go to another site or download material to understand your question.

Comment: Sorry David, I did remove the link. Thank you.